# How to get text of element that couple levels above from link that was clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap library and their dropdowns. Here is example of one of the rows in my table:

```
<tr class="mattersRow">
    <td> … </td>
    <td class="danger">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdownSelector" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                SELECT
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel" role="menu">
                <li>
                    <a class="menuItemQB" href="#">
                        Put this text instead of SELECT
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> … </li>
                <li> … </li>
                <li> … </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the `td` I have SELECT link, that has dropdown when I click on it. I need get text of the link that inside of dropdown. When I click on "Put this text instead of SELECT" and put this text instead of SELECT and remove "danger" class from link

I use the following jQuery:

```
$('.menuItemQB').bind('click', function () {
    alert($(this).html());
    // Here I need to put $(this).html() instead of SELECT and remove class='danger'
});
```

I don't know hot to get access to this link...

```
<a class="dropdownSelector" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> SELECT </a>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a.dropdownSelector')`?

Comment: Are you asking how to traverse back up to .dropdown and then find .dropdownSelector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like this :

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown').children(':first');
```

Doc : [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/), [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/).

Comment: Thanks. Will accept in 10 min, cause you were first one, who answered

Comment: You are my helper for today =) Thanks for the links. Will read right now

Comment: @Bryuk Everybody here tries hard to help :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a.dropdownSelector')
```

Answer (score 1):

Traverse up to parent of element you want, then search within that element

```
$('.menuItemQB').click(function(){
   var link= $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdownSelector');

    alert(link.text())
})
```

jQuery API is full of traversal methods. An hour looking through the descriptions and  examples for various methods will be time well spent. There is a whole subsection in left nav for `Traversing`

[API Docs- Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I've started to read book about jQuery, but my knowledge in jQuery still low...

Comment: Make the API your best friend for learning, refer to it often